# Reading and Writing XML files with unknown encoding in Perl?

Tags: html, xml, perl, utf-8, latin1

I am picking up pieces of someone else's large project and trying to right the wrongs. The problem is, I'm just not sure what the *correct* ways are.

So, I am cURLing a bunch of HTML pages, then writing it to files with simple commands like:

```
$src = `curl http://google.com`;
open FILE, ">output.html";
print FILE $src;
close FILE;
```

Now I wanted those to be saved as UTF-8. What is it saved as? Then I am reading the html file in using the same basic 'open' command, parsing the html with regex calls, and using string concatenation to make a big string and writing it to an XML file (using the same  code as above). I have already started using XML::Writer instead, but now I must go through and fix the files that have inaccurate encoding.

So, I don't have the html anymore, but I still have the XML that have to display proper characters. Here is an example: http://filevo.com/wkkixmebxlmh.html

The main problem is detecting and replacing the character in question with a "\x{2019}" that displays in editors properly. But I can't figure out a regex to actually capture the character in the wild.

**UPDATE:**

I still cannot detect the ALT-0146 character that's in the XML file I uploaded to Filevo above. I've tried opening it in UTF-8, and searching for /\x{2019}/, /chr(0x2019)/, and just /’/, nothing.

Comment: `use utf8` is exclusively for treating _your script's source code_ as being UTF-8 encoded. It does not have anything, anything, to do with the encoding of any inputs and outputs of your script, including STDOUT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure you are producing output in UTF-8, apply the `utf8` layer to the output stream using `binmode`

```
open FILE, '>output.html';
binmode FILE, ':utf8';
```

or in the 3-argument `open` call

```
open FILE, '>:utf8', 'output.html'
```

Arbitrary input is trickier. If you are lucky, HTML input will tell you its encoding early on:

```
wget http://www.google.com/ -O foo ; head -1 foo

<!doctype html><html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; 
charset=ISO-8859-1"><title>Google</title><script>window.google=
{kEI:"xgngTYnYIoPbgQevid3cCg",kEXPI:"23933,28505,29134,29229,29658,
29695,29795,29822,29892,30111,30174,30215,30275,30562",kCSI:
{e:"23933,28505,29134,29229,29658,29695,29795,29822,29892,30111,
30174,30215,30275,30562",ei:"xgngTYnYIoPbgQevid3cCg",expi:
"23933,28505,29134,29229,29658,29695,29795,29822,29892,30111,
30174,30215,30275,30562"},authuser:0,ml:function(){},kHL:"en",
time:function(){return(new Date).getTime()},
```

Ah, there it is: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; 
charset=ISO-8859-1">`. Now you may continue to read input as raw bytes and find some way to decode those bytes with the known encoding. [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Encode&mode=all) can help with this.

Comment: If you really want things simple, stop using curl to get the HTML. `use LWP::UserAgent; my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(); my $response = $ua->get('http://www.google.com'); $response->decoded_content;` HTTP::Response will decode the content based on the headers into an perl internal unicode string; then you can simply apply a unicode binmode to your output and it'll just work.

Comment: this is great advice for improving the system, but I still cannot detect the ALT-0146 character that's in the XML file I uploaded to Filevo. I've tried opening it in UTF-8, and searching for /\x{2019}/, /chr(0x2019)/, and just /’/, nothing.

Comment: @Sho Minaminoto: When you pull down that file into perl and use a regex to pull out that character (since you know the characters before and after that difficult character), what does it say the one you are interested in looks like?  You can print it into a file and do things like that.

Comment: You can open the XML file as a text file and see it. It appears like the letter 'a' plus a currency sign, but it depends on what editor I open it with.

Answer (score 4):

Discovering the encoding of a HTML document is **hard**.  See http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-character-encoding and especially that it requires a "7-step algorithm; step 4 has 2 sub-steps, the first of which has 7 branches, one of which has 8 sub-steps, one of which actually links to a separate algorithm that itself has 7 steps... It goes on like that for a while."

This is what I used for a my limited needs in parsing HTML files.

```
my $CHARACTER_SET_CLASS = '\w:.()-';

     # X(HT)?ML: http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset
     /\<\?xml [^>]*(?<= )encoding=[\'\"]?([$CHARACTER_SET_CLASS]+)/ ||
     # X?HTML: http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-character-encoding
     /\<meta [^>]*\bcharset=["']?([$CHARACTER_SET_CLASS]+)/i ||
     # CSS: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset
     /\@charset "([^\"]*)"/ ||
```

Answer (score 1):

I am referring to the updated part of your question (next time [open a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for a separate topic). This is a hex dump of your file (please refrain in the future from making helpers jump through burning hoops to get at your example data):

```
0000  3c 78 6d 6c 3e 0d 0a 3c  70 65 72 73 6f 6e 4e 61  <xml>␍␤< personNa
0010  6d 65 3e 47 2e 20 50 65  74 65 72 20 44 61 80 41  me>G. Pe ter Da�A
0020  6c 6f 69 61 3c 2f 70 65  72 73 6f 6e 4e 61 6d 65  loia</pe rsonName
0030  3e 0d 0a 3c 2f 78 6d 6c  3e 0d 0a                 >␍␤</xml >␍␤
```

You said you know the character should be `’`, but it got totally mangled. It can't be 0x80 in any encoding. This looks like a paste accident where you transferred data between editors/clipboards instead of dealing with just files. If that's not the case, then your cow orker produced a wrong you are not able to right algorithmically.